supabase auth signout automatic redirect to sign-out page
How to change config os supabase auth signout to avoid automatic redirect to sign-out page?
code:
supabase.auth.signOut();

above code result to automatic redirect to sign-out in my nextjs app. and i want to redirect to my main homepage instead!
I've go over the docs, i've read online forums.

Have you tried using a server action in combination with middleware redirection?
read more here:https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-nextjs#nextjs-middleware
Signout server action:


export async function signout() {
  const supabase = createClient();
  try {
    const { error } = await supabase.auth.signOut();
    if (error) {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  revalidatePath("/", "layout");
}



in your middleware


try {
  const {
    data: {
      user
    },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

  // If user is visiting any admin routes, redirect them to the home page if they're not signed in
  if (!user &&
    request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/admin") &&
    request.nextUrl.pathname !== "/admin/login" &&
    request.nextUrl.pathname !== "/admin/sign-up"
  ) {
    console.log("User is not signed in");
    return NextResponse.redirect(`${request.nextUrl.origin}/admin/login`);
  }

  // If user is signed in, hide the login page
  if (user && request.nextUrl.pathname === "/admin/login") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(`${request.nextUrl.origin}/admin`);
  }
  // If none of the above conditions are met, continue to the requested route
  return NextResponse.next();
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error in middleware:", error);
  // Handle the error as needed
}
return response;
}



Hope this helps. I took it from one of my apps so it's specific to my situation
